# lightbox dynamic image retrieval

Tags: php, jquery

I am constructing a lighbox gallery, currently experimenting with FancyBox (http://fancybox.net) and ColorBox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox).

By default you have to include a link to the large version of the image so that the Lightbox can display it. However, I am wanting to have the image link URLs pointing to a script rather than directly to the image file. So for example, instead of:

```
<a href="mysite/images/myimage.jpg">
```

I want to do:

```
<a href="mysite/photos/view/abc123">
```

The above URL points to a function:

```
public function actionPhotos($view)
{
    $photo=Photo::model()->find('name=:name', array(':name'=>$view));

    if(!empty($photo))
    {
        $user=$photo->user;

        $this->renderPartial('_photo', array('user'=>$user, 'photo'=>$photo, true));
    }
}
```

At some point in the future the function will also update the view count of the image.

Now this approach is working to an extent - most images load up but some do not load up (the lightbox gets displayed in a malformed state). I think the reason for this is because it is not processing the function quick enough. For example when I click the "next" button it needs to go to the URL, process the function and retreive/output the response.

Does anybody know how I can get this working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "width" and "height" attributes on my image tags and it works fine now.